# cannot access php json decoded multi dimensional array values curl

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, multidimensional-array

when i execute the below code to access koinex ticker api , I am getting an array but how can i display only certain values :

```
echo $response[0][0][1];

echo $response['prices']['BTC'][0];
```

code :

```
<?php

$getCurrency = "inr";
$displayArrayOutput = true;

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://koinex.in/api/ticker',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Something here'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
} else {
    if($displayArrayOutput){
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        print_r($response);

    }
    else{
        header("Content-type:application/json");
        echo 'touine';
    }
}


echo $response[0][0][1];
echo $response['prices']['BTC'][0];

?>
```

sorry a little new to php , open to any other kind of approach for decoding json

Comment: why not var_dump($response) to see what the array looks like?

Comment: If u already have the array made try `echo json_encode(array_keys($array))` that will output the keys of the array.

An example, lets say u get a json object like `{"field1":"val1", "field2":"value2"}`, the outout will be "field1", "field2"

Comment: `echo $response['prices']['BTC'];` ... results in `598499.0`

Comment: thanks it work but can any one tell why i dont need [0] ?

Comment: Because it is not an array its an object containing other objects, specially if you remove the `,true` from the `json_decode()`